# Custom shortcuts don't work with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Just formatted and installed `Windows 10` last weekend. Tried to recreate my usual shortcuts but they don't work. For example for `Paintbrush` I go to `windows/system32/` and create a shortcut of mspaint.exe then in its properties I type my combo in the "shortcut key field", hit ok. But the combo doesnt' do anything.

Any idea? Default Windows shortcuts all work though.

Comment: Where is your shortcut saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcuts with custom key combinations must be placed in the Start Menu or Desktop (This has been the case since Windows XP) to launch the program in question.

This means either `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`, `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` or `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`.

If the shortcut is in a location other than this, the shortcut will only work to bring that program into the foreground (This doesn't work with all applications. I just tested this with VLC and it didn't work, but ImageMagik Display did.)

More information [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/134552).